# Finding the searched text in google search result with selenium webdriver in Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver and having a problem

i googled something and the result appeared.now  i want to see if the first 5 results contain the searched text or not.

as example:

i want to search for the text "selenium webdriver". now i want to check if the first 5 results contains the text "selenium webdriver" or not.

Here is my part:

```
chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");

IWebElement searchText = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/fieldset[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/input"));
searchText.SendKeys("selenium webdriver");

IWebElement searchButton = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Name("btnG"));
searchButton.Click() ;

IWebElement resultingText = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("selenium webdriver"));
```

this line is throwing an exception :

```
// IWebElement resultingText = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("selenium webdriver"));
```

can any one help me in this issue?

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: The element could not be found

Comment: You want to check if the first 5 results contain "selenium webdriver", and is that it? What do you want to do? Click the first one?

Comment: to click any of the five. but first of all it should be checked that if they contain the text or not.

Comment: please help . i don't get what is the prob with this code

Comment: Post a screenshot & the HTML of what link you intend to click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the exception because a **LinkText** locator will find an exact match of the link text, so it's looking for a link that contains only the text "selenium webdriver".  If you look at the result of the Google search, an exact match is not present, so you get the exception.

This code will print out every link contained within the first page of the search results.  From here, you can modify this to check the first five to see if it contains text that matches your criteria:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq"));
element.SendKeys("selenium webdriver");

// Get the search results panel that contains the link for each result.
IWebElement resultsPanel = driver.FindElement(By.Id("search"));

// Get all the links only contained within the search result panel.
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> searchResults = resultsPanel.FindElements(By.XPath(".//a"));

// Print the text for every link in the search results.
foreach (IWebElement result in searchResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
}
```

Comment: thank you. thanks for the effort . it's working.:) @PocketDews

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using terrible xpath. Try something like `//input[@id='gbqfq']`
2. When you're searching something by text, it is registry sensitive
3. For your case with 5 results, you can use the following (I'm not familiar with C#, so here's the python code, you should understand it):

   ```
   first_five = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='rso']//div//h3/a")[:5]     
   #returns the list of first five result links
   for result in first_five:
       assert "selenium webriver" in result.text.lower(), "Result does not contain 'selenium webdriver'" 
       # lower - to get rid off registry troubles
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable and better to use CSS selector or if you are willing to use only XPath. please choose 'fire path'. which generates short and precise Xpath and place it in your code. avoid using such lengthy Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using **vb.net**, **selenium**. It works for me. I hope this might be helpful for reference.

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium'
Module SearchResults
Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim Browser As Chrome.ChromeDriver = New Chrome.ChromeDriver("C:\SeleniumLive\DriverFiles\")
        Browser.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in")
        For i = 0 To 4
            If Browser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")) Is Nothing Then
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End If
        Next
        If Browser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")) IsNot Nothing Then
            Browser.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Sumit Shitole" & Keys.Enter)
        End If
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        For pageNumber As Integer = 1 To 8 Step 1
            Console.WriteLine("......Result from page " & pageNumber & "..........")
            Dim results As New List(Of IWebElement)(Browser.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".r>a")))
            For Each result As IWebElement In results
                Console.WriteLine(result.Text)
            Next
            Browser.FindElement(By.Id("pnnext")).Click()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
        Browser.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
```